# Error with knitr when knitting Rmd to PDF, but code runs fine?

Tags: r, knitr

I'm trying to knit an Rmd file, and the code runs fine, but when I attempt to knit I get back and error once it gets to my first chunk of R code:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x) : 
  cannot coerce class '"function"' to a data.frame
Calls: <Anonymous> ... merge.default -> merge -> as.data.frame -> as.data.frame.default
Execution halted
```

If I delete my first chunk of code, a similar error pops up for whatever is the new first chunk of code.

Edit: Here are my first

````
 ---
title: "[title]"
author: "[Name]"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  word_document:
    fig_caption: yes
---


library(knitr)  
library(png) 

#The code book of the two data sets can be found in these two links:


wwwn.cdc.gov/Nchs/Nhanes/2015-2016/DEMO_I.htm  
wwwn.cdc.gov/Nchs/Nhanes/2015-2016/CBQ_I.htm  




install.packages("Hmisc")


library(Hmisc)

demo <- sasxport.get("https://wwwn.cdc.gov/Nchs/Nhanes/2015-2016/DEMO_I.XPT")

cbq <- sasxport.get("https://wwwn.cdc.gov/Nchs/Nhanes/2015-2016/CBQ_I.XPT")


`str(demo)`
`str(cbq)`


```{r}
eat <- merge(demo, cbq, by="seqn")
```



```{r}
dim(eat)
# = 52 columns
# = 9,971 rows

# OR can use
ncol(eat)
nrow(eat)
```
````

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you provide your code or an minimal working example?

Comment: @J_F sure! It's just simple functions. See my edits in the original post.

Comment: I think J_F is imagining something we can copy out to R and run ourselves. Look up making a reprex.

Comment: Okay, the issue there is that I don't think reprex supports Rmd, and the error only comes with knitr on the Rmd, the Rscript runs fine. I'll just paste  in all of what I have instead of using reprex. It should be there now.

Comment: *"don't think reprex supports Rmd"*, how is that? Much of the code in your current question's Rmd is not actually code: `library(...)` for instance is just text, not within a block (`demo` and `cbq` are never defined). That could have something to do with your problems. For me, `demo` is still a *function*, and running `merge(demo, anything_else_here)` fails with that error.

Comment: @r2evans sorry, new to Stack so having issues tagging in responses. As I mention in another reply, even when I put those text into an r code chunk, I still run into the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is reproducibility and undefined variables. Much of your code in your question is not within a code chunk, so it will *print* (albeit not as code) but will not create variables, load libraries, etc. With that in mind, you may realize then that `demo` and `cqb` are never defined within the document.

That means that if either exists as an object in the base R environment, then they exist but are not what you think they are. In this case, `demo` is in fact a function `utils::demo` and is available, so `merge` tries to do something with it. Unfortunately, as you might expect, there is no logic to be able to do merge-like operations on a function.

I can reproduce you error on my console:

```r
ls()
# character(0)

# 'demo' not defined as a frame, so still utils::demo
# 'cbq' does not matter, because 'merge' cannot get past the problem with 'demo'

merge(demo, cbq)
# Error in as.data.frame.default(x) : 
#   cannot coerce class '"function"' to a data.frame
```

The fix might be to put your initial code within a code block.

I don't know what you intend to do with the URLs in there, but here is a less malformed Rmd:

````
---
title: "[title]"
author: "[Name]"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  word_document:
    fig_caption: yes
---

The code book of the two data sets can be found in these two links:

- wwwn.cdc.gov/Nchs/Nhanes/2015-2016/DEMO_I.htm  
- wwwn.cdc.gov/Nchs/Nhanes/2015-2016/CBQ_I.htm  

```{r}
library(knitr)  
library(png) 
install.packages("Hmisc")
library(Hmisc)
demo <- sasxport.get("https://wwwn.cdc.gov/Nchs/Nhanes/2015-2016/DEMO_I.XPT")
cbq <- sasxport.get("https://wwwn.cdc.gov/Nchs/Nhanes/2015-2016/CBQ_I.XPT")
```

`str(demo)`

`str(cbq)`

```{r}
eat <- merge(demo, cbq, by="seqn")
```

```{r}
dim(eat)
# = 52 columns
# = 9,971 rows

# OR can use
ncol(eat)
nrow(eat)
```
````

Some notes about this:

- Unless this is intended to always run in a sterile R environment (e.g., docker container), then I find `install.packages` to be not only poor design but also not fair to anybody else that might use this Rmd document: perhaps I'm intending to stay on a stable older package version (reproducibility!), but just by rendering your document, my package is revocably upgraded.
- You `` `str(demo)` `` is printing the literal string `"str(demo)"` in fixed-width font, but running nothing. This might either go in a code chunk, or you can use inline-code by using `` `r str(demo)` `` (that's backtick, "r", space, code, backtick).

Comment: I appreciate all of your feedback. This is for an assignment, so everything prior to the "merge" is what was given already. When I initially tried to put the everything into an code chunk like you have, it still would elicit an error at the merge. For those particular commands that you cite, it is intentional for it to not be a code chunk as I'm not trying to have the output in my knitted document, just want the code quoted.

Comment: Also: When I try to use the code you posted, which i believe I have tried before, the error that outputs is now regarding the install function (which aligns with the original problem: whatever is the first R code function attempted to be knitted, knitr runs into an error).

Comment: Okay, I was able to get it to work! Thank you so much for your help. One of the issues I had was running the install.packages. Once I got rid of that (and used the inline-code syntax you gave me) it worked! Much appreciated, good sir.

Comment: If that resolved your question, please accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, my apologies. Stack noob here. Appreciate it!